# Unable to create model based forms rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, form-helpers

I have model based form:

```
<h2>Add New Credit Card</h2>
<%= form_for @credit_card do |f| %>
     some fields
<% end %>
```

routes:

```
resources :credit_card

credit_card_index GET    /credit_card(.:format)                       credit_card#index
                     POST   /credit_card(.:format)                       credit_card#create
     new_credit_card GET    /credit_card/new(.:format)                   credit_card#new
    edit_credit_card GET    /credit_card/:id/edit(.:format)              credit_card#edit
         credit_card GET    /credit_card/:id(.:format)                   credit_card#show
                     PATCH  /credit_card/:id(.:format)                   credit_card#update
                     PUT    /credit_card/:id(.:format)                   credit_card#update
                     DELETE /credit_card/:id(.:format)                   credit_card#destroy
```

controller:

```
def new
    @credit_card = CreditCard.new
end
```

When I try to render by form it says:

```
undefined method `credit_cards_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000004c37680>:0x00000004c34570>
Did you mean?  credit_card_path
               credit_card_index_path
               credit_card_url
```

Its a model based form, for now I have nothing in model. I just want to render and submit will go to create method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the [`Singular Resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#singular-resources):

```
resources :credit_card
```

Where you have to use [`Plural Resources`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default):

```
resources :credit_cards
```

Comment: It all depends on what you need. I've also posted the links to the documentation so look at it.

Answer (score 2):

In your routes, use plural for `resources` definition.

```
resources :credit_cards
```

That will generate your routes like

```
credit_cards GET    /credit_cards/:id(.:format)                   credit_card#show
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `resources :credit_cards` instead of `resources :credit_card`